# Symfony 2 and Goutte

Tags: php, symfony, iconv, goutte

I want to get some information from a site with CP1251 encoding.

```
use Goutte\Client;
use Nonlux\Bundle\Entity\News;
....
protected function downloadQueuePage(){
    $cli = new Client();
    $url=array_pop($this->_url);
    $this->output->writeln("http://www.baikal-daily.ru" . $url);
    $cra=$cli->request("get", "http://www.baikal-daily.ru" . $url);
    $news=new News();
    $news->setSiteId(1);
    $news->setUrl($url);
    $news->setTitle($cra->filter("#content .main h3")->text());
 }
```

Default Crawler returns on some pages empty nodes h1, but it exist on the page and layout like is valid.
After the magic of the code Groute, Crawler and iconv.
In one case, I got:

```
В Улан-Удэ трёхлетний мальчик упал в открытый колодец
упал в открытый колодец
�й колодец
дец
�
```

a rather that:

```
В Улан-Удэ трёхлетний мальчик упал в открытый колодец
```

Another time I got a lot of  beep signals from the console, which dumps the received pages.
How can I solve this problem? Where to find the source of evil?

Comment: Wake up. It's the UTF-8th century. ;)

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately UTF-revolution has not reached the consciousness development of the kitchen.Yes. Unfortunately UTF-revolution has not reached the consciousness development of the kitchen. My goal  news aggregation other sites.

Comment: Sorry. I have valid data. It`s only console bug.

Comment: But another part of news is loaded as binary data and get an exception.